# Node/Express API connection refusal by local Postgres

Tags: node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js, windows-subsystem-for-linux

Trying to diagnose a problem as I build a Sequelize skeleton for my API.

I'm using WSL, and I have a Postgres server set up in PGAdmin. Assuming my creds aren't the issue, am I missing something?

```js
const app = require("./app");
const http = require("http");
const server = http.createServer(app);

const { Sequelize } = require("sequelize");
const sequelize = new Sequelize('postgres://fakeuser:fakepass@localhost:5432/kobold_condominium') // Example for postgres

server.listen(3000);

server.on("listening", async () => {
    console.log("Server is listening for requests on port 3000.");
    try {
        await sequelize.authenticate();
        console.log("Database connection successful.");
    } catch (error) {
        console.log("Database connection:" + error);
    }
});
```

I consistently get this output:

> Database connection:SequelizeConnectionRefusedError: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:5432

Am I missing something? I didn't think there would be Windows/WSL issues; any ideas?

Comment: Are both Node and the PG server running in WSL?

Comment: PG server is in Windows; I thought it wouldn't matter, since it's a network address. Am I wrong?

Comment: See [Accessing Windows networking apps from Linux (host IP)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/networking#accessing-windows-networking-apps-from-linux-host-ip)